# How to find what is using the connections in my connection pool

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, ado.net, connection-pooling

I have a problem in the code that I have written using .NET.

The problem is that somewhere I have some dodgy database code that means that after some time I get the following error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may
>   have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool
>   size was reached.

I know that it is because somewhere I haven't disposed of one of my datareaders or something similar which means it still has the connection open so its not being returned to the pool. I'm having a bit of problem finding where this is happening in my code though.

So my question:

Is there any way to query the connection pool to find out what its in use connections are doing. I'm just looking for a way to find what query is being run to allow me to find the offending piece of code.

For what its worth I don't have permissions to run an activity monitor on the database in question to find out that way.

Comment: what version of the Framework are you using?

Comment: Connection pool is a shared reasource. It's SAD that there's no way to know who is using the resource for troubleshooting. Connection.Open should be something we can easily intercept, and track connections as they're taken from and returned to the pool, but so far, I'm having a hard time finding a way. Maybe something with SignalFx hooks into the CLR (it does method replacement to track queries) could help with this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there any way to query the
>   connection pool to find out what its
>   in use connections are doing.

No. Not really. The connection pool is something that your application maintains (actually a `List<DbConnectionInternal>` ) If you really wanted to you could get to the connections in the pool via reflection or if you are debugging, via a local or watch window (see below), but you can't get to what's happening on that connection from there or which object should have called Connection.Close (or Dispose). So that doesn't help

[image]

If you're lucky you can execute sp_who or sp_who2 at the moment  you get the timeout when you've run out of pooled connections when but its highly likely that most of the results are going to look like this .

```
SPID Staus    Login Hostname  Blkby DBname Command          ....
---- -------  ----- --------- ----- ------ ---------------- 
79   sleeping uName WebServer .     YourDb AWAITING COMMAND .....
80   sleeping uName WebServer .     YourDb AWAITING COMMAND .....
81   sleeping uName WebServer .     YourDb AWAITING COMMAND .....
82   sleeping uName WebServer .     YourDb AWAITING COMMAND .....
```

Which means that yes indeed your application has opened a lot of connection and didn't close them and isn't even doing anything with them.

The best way to combat this is to profile your application use the [ADO.NET Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503.aspx) and keep a close eye on `NumberOfReclaimedConnections` and also do a thorough code review.

If you're really desperate you can Clear the pool when you encounter this problem.

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("YourCnnString"))
{

     try
     {
            cnn.Open();
     }
     catch (InvalidOperationException)
     {
             SqlConnection.ClearPool(cnn);
     }
     cnn.Open();

}
```

I do however caution you against this because it has the potential of choking your DB server because it allows your application to open as many connections as the server will allow before it just runs out of resources.

Comment: Thanks Conrad. That seems like a pretty comprehensive answer and said what I suspected. In the end I decided I was unhappy with the way the database access had been written and ended up just overhauling it entirely but this is useful for the future, especially the pointers on how to find the connection pool in the watch window. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried loading up SSMS and running `sp_who2` on the database in question?

```
USE [SomeDatabase]
EXEC sp_who2
```

That should show you what's happening at a moment in time.

Comment: Just tried it (sp_who2 if you want to correct your typo) but it only returned my current connection. I tried changing my connection to use the same connection settings as the code in question but still only showed my one row whcih seemed to be my current connection. I assume this is the same permissions problem that stops me running activity monitor. :( Thanks for the suggestion though.